# How determine if the popup page is open or not?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension and I'm looking how to find out (from the background page) if the popup page is open or not. I looked into [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) but I'm not sure if that's gonna help me at this or if there's a simpler way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the following chrome API call from your background page fetch if the popup view is open:

```
var views = chrome.extension.getViews({ type: "popup" });

//views => [] //popup is closed
//views => [DOMWindow] //popup is open
```

If it returns an empty array then your popup is not open, if it returns an array with your popups DOMWindow object, then your popup is open.

If you have multiple popups in one plugin then you could check for the existence of some global variable in the returned DOMWindow to disambiguate.

Comment: Thank god for this, I previously thought it was impossible after searching around for a week straight.

Comment: This doesn't work with Manifest 3 anymore

Comment: giving `chrome.extension.getViews` is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Alternative method:
`extension.getViews({ type: "popup" })` will not work on mobile, because the popup is not actually a popup.
As a workaround, you can set a variable (say, document.title) in the popup's document, and test its value in the background page.
For instance, in your popup's HTML code:

```
<title>My awesome extension</title>
```

And in `background.js`:

```
if (document.title == "My awesome extension") {
```