# google chrome bug?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

this message appears all the time in chrome developer tool's console:

```
Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. miscellaneous_bindings:232
chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnDisconnect miscellaneous_bindings:232
Error in event handler for 'undefined': Cannot read property 'instanceId' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'instanceId' of undefined
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content_js_min.js:2:372)
    at chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content_js_min.js:1:182
    at miscellaneous_bindings:276:11
    at [object Object].dispatch (event_bindings:203:41)
    at Object.<anonymous> (miscellaneous_bindings:235:27) event_bindings:207
chrome.Event.dispatch event_bindings:207
chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnDisconnect miscellaneous_bindings:235
```

is this a bug in chrome or there is something wrong in my chrome installation?

Comment: On your website, or just in general? If just in general, then I'd say: disable all extensions and check again, if it's still there then yes, it's probably a bug in Chrome, but either way it doesn't belong here if it is just in general. If it's not just in general, you need to show some code.

Comment: Something is wrong in whatever extension has the id `mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja`

Comment: ... which appears to be the Google Dictionary extension - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja

Comment: Can you find the solution yourself [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106519/port-error-could-not-establish-connection-receiving-end-does-not-exist-in-chr)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on some googling, this is a problem with a chrome extension, but it may not be clear which. (For me, it was Feedly).

The quickest way to find out which is causing the problem:

1. Disable all your chrome extensions. (Chrome menu > tools > extensions)
2. Refresh a page - hopefully the port error should be gone now
3. Re-enable your extensions one by one, refreshing the page after each, 'til the error pops up again in the console. You should now have your culprit.

I know this could be a pain if there are a lot of extensions :/ personally, I took it as a chance to prune the unused / unworthy extensions while I was going through them.

Comment: You are spot on. For me it was Download Accelerator Plus (DAP) extension.

Answer (score 22):

It seems to be a problem with the [Google Dictionary (by Google)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja)

[This script](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content_js_min.js) doesn't seem to exist or is not accessible by that port.

Comment: I'm looking a little bit further into it.

Comment: @AladdinHoms definitely not! Others might have the same doubt as you and end up here and to get some clarification :)

Comment: I had same error in console but disabling ChromeToPhone cleared it.  Seems Google are lax in updating their own extensions?

Comment: @Darren Is right, disable Chrome to phone extension and the error goes away. Strange. But also Google provide a new extension these days called Chrome To Mobile, how it differs I'm not 100% sure and why they didn't just update chrome to phone i don't know either. But once again try installing "Chrome To Mobile" instead of "Chrome To Phone"

Comment: I have the same problem caused by th "Speed Tracer" extension, by disabling this extension the message no longer appears.

Comment: @ragebunny The new "Chrome to Mobile" appears to support sending to multiple devices, for instance if you have a tablet and a phone.