# Chrome Extension: Get active page source code without using jquery (unchecked runtime error)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've been using a background script combined with jquery to get the source code of a page with a Chrome Extension but now, I'd like to capture the source code only when I click on the extension pop-up.

Here is what I have been trying to do:

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tab Source Code</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="getCodeButton">Get Source Code</button>
    <pre id="sourceCode"></pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var getCodeButton = document.getElementById("getCodeButton");
  getCodeButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { action: "getSourceCode" }, function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action === "getSourceCode") {
    var sourceCode = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
    sendResponse({ sourceCode: sourceCode });
  }
});
```

When I run the screen, I get the following error message:
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

My manifest seems ok:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "xxxx",
    "description": "xxxx",
    "version": "1.01",
    "author": "xxxx",


"permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/",
        "https://*/",
        "<all_urls>",
        "notifications",
        "webRequest",
        "webNavigation",
        "management",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "http://*/*",
        "background",
        "alarms",
        "https://*/*"
    
    ],
```

"externally_connectable": {
"matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
},

```
 "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
    
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
            "js": ["content.js"]

        }],
    
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "logo.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

I have tried multiple solutions found on stackexchange to communicate with content.js but I haven't found one that works.

I tried this:
[Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. In Chromiume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106519/port-error-could-not-establish-connection-receiving-end-does-not-exist-in-chr)
but it doesn't solve my problem.

any idea ?

thanks

Comment: What does `console.log(tabs[0].id)` show?

Comment: @Barmar it shows the ID of the active tab (ex: 1312273983)

Comment: `onMessage` should be `onMessageExternal`

Comment: @Barmar tried it but same error message :(

Comment: Did you try other solutions at the linked question?

Comment: Either use chrome.scripting.executeScript in the popup script or [re-inject content scripts explicitly](/q/10994324) after reloading/installing the extension.

Comment: @Barmar, no, onMessageExternal is for an entirely different use case and no, there are no solutions in that topic, which should be deleted as it's full of outdated API that were removed from ManifestV3 and deprecated 5+ years ago in ManifestV2.

Comment: @wOxxOm can the source code of the page be accessed from popup.js and using executeScript? I thought I could only access the source code of popup.html?

Comment: executeScript runs in the web page, it's the entire purpose of this method.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, I had the wrong understanding of it, thanks for pointing out!