# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. While building a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

The goal of this Chrome extension is to enable users to capture screenshots of a selected area within the browser just like this extension (`https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edlifbnjlicfpckhgjhflgkeeibhhcii`). Below is the code for the extension, including the manifest file, popup HTML, popup JavaScript, content script, and background script.

//manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "storage", "tabs"],

  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },

  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Extension</title>
    <script src="./jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="btn">Start Selection</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
  console.log(chrome);
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { action: "startSelection" });
  });
});
```

contentScript.js

```
// contentScript.js
var start = {};
var end = {};
var isSelecting = false;

$(window).on("mousedown", function (event) {
  isSelecting = true;
  start.x = event.pageX;
  start.y = event.pageY;

  $("#selection").removeClass("complete");
  $("#start").text("(" + start.x + "," + start.y + ")");
  $("#selection").css({
    left: start.x,
    top: start.y,
  });
});

$(window).on("mousemove", function (event) {
  if (!isSelecting) {
    return;
  }

  end.x = event.pageX;
  end.y = event.pageY;

  $("#selection").css({
    left: start.x < end.x ? start.x : end.x,
    top: start.y < end.y ? start.y : end.y,
    width: Math.abs(start.x - end.x),
    height: Math.abs(start.y - end.y),
  });
});

$(window).on("mouseup", function (event) {
  isSelecting = false;
  $("#selection").addClass("complete");
  $("#end").text("(" + end.x + "," + end.y + ")");

  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    action: "sendSnapshot",
    start: start,
    end: end,
  });
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action === "blurTab") {
    $("body").css("filter", "blur(5px)");
  }
  if (request.action === "unblurTab") {
    $("body").css("filter", "none");
  }
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action === "startSelection") {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "blurTab" });
  }
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action === "sendSnapshot") {
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab({ format: "png" }, function (dataUrl) {
      // Extract the selected area from the snapshot
      const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      const img = new Image();
      img.onload = function () {
        canvas.width = Math.abs(request.start.x - request.end.x);
        canvas.height = Math.abs(request.start.y - request.end.y);
        ctx.drawImage(
          img,
          request.start.x,
          request.start.y,
          canvas.width,
          canvas.height,
          0,
          0,
          canvas.width,
          canvas.height
        );
        const snapshotUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        // Do something with the snapshot URL, for example, send it to the server
        console.log(snapshotUrl);

        // Unblur the tab
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(sender.tab.id, { action: "unblurTab" });
      };
      img.src = dataUrl;
    });
  }
}
);
```

I don't even know what is causing the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9106519/519413